# Integral issues, in deriving the Feynman path integral

Tags: path-integral

In deriving the path integral, one often finds an expression of this type:

$$\langle x_N|e^{-iH\Delta t} e^{-iH \Delta t} \ldots e^{-iH\Delta t}|x_0\rangle =\tag{1}$$
$$ \langle x_N|e^{-iH\Delta t}\left(\int dx_{N-1}|x_{N-1}\rangle\langle x_{N-1}|\right)e^{-iH\Delta t}\left(\int dx_{N-2}|x_{N-2}\rangle\langle x_{N-2}|\right)e^{-iH\Delta t}\ldots |x_{0}\rangle \tag{2}$$

which is claimed to be writable, equivalently, as follows:

$$\int dx_{N-1}\int dx_{N-2}...\int dx_1 \langle x_N|e^{-iH\Delta t}|x_{N-1}\rangle\langle x_{N-1}|e^{-iH\Delta t}|x_{N-2}\rangle\langle x_{N-2}|\ldots|x_1\rangle\langle x_1|e^{-iH\Delta t}|x_0\rangle \tag{3}$$

But, I am confused as to the use of the notation. I am probably wrong, but all I see are violations of the properties of integrals.

- In (3), what are we integrating exactly? Is (3) a claim that we integrate the braket terms $N$ times, once for each $dx_i$?
- I am familiar with the integrated term being between the $int$ and the $dx$ signs. However, here it seems the notation is $\int dx_{N-1}$ but the integral is perform edfor the entire expression that follows it. For example, these are not the same:  $\int xdx \neq (\int dx) x$?
- In (2) why is one allowed to break the $\int dx_{N-1}$ to the front of the expression, leaving its friends $|x_{N-1}\rangle\langle x_{N-1}|$ behind? Doesn't that changes the whole integral? For instance if I normalize $\int \psi(x) dx=\mathbb{I}$, then inject it into an expression $x^2 \mathbb{I}\to x^2\int \psi(x) dx$ on the grounds that the integral is equal to unity, but then I play with the integral moving terms around as follows $\int dx x^2 \psi(x)$, then I do not see how I still injected the identity into my expression. Clearly, the result for $\int dx x^2 \psi(x)$ are not the same as those for $x^2\int \psi(x) dx$. But I have made the same changes as going from (2) to (3).

Comment: Look for example to the integral over $x_{N-1}$ (the leftmost integral in your equation (1)). Do you realize that *all the dependence in $x_{N-1}$* is contained inside these parentheses? So if *nothing else depends on $x_{N-1}$* then everything else can be treated as constants with respect to that particular integral and can be put inside it. That is all that is being done.

Comment: Moreover you seem to be having a notational confusion. In (3) all those integral signs with all those $dx_i$ mean *exactly* to integrate everything else that is to the right of them. We often encounter large expressions and then it is common to write the integration measure to the left of the integrand. So you'll see a lot of $\int dx f(x)$ and that means to integrate $f(x)$, not that $f(x)$ is on the outside of the integral.